# Using KIF to click links in UITextView

Tags: ios, ios8

Is it possible to use KIF to click links in UITextViews? Using Accessibility Inspector seems to treat the UITextView as a single view and does not seem to recognize links.

Comment: Was able to achieve same thing by using TTTAttributedLabel. Starting to think I should just use that regardless if it's multi line or not.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that links in `UITextView` objects need a longer press to activate than a standard tap with KIF. I solved this by writing my own test step using a category on KIFUITestActor. The code tries to find the text you want to tap inside of the `UITextView` and then long presses it.

```
- (void)tapText:(NSString *)text inTextViewWithAccessibilityIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier
{
    [self runBlock:^KIFTestStepResult(NSError *__autoreleasing *error) {
        UITextView *textView = nil;
        UIAccessibilityElement *element = nil;
        [self waitForAccessibilityElement:&element view:&textView withIdentifier:identifier tappable:YES];
        KIFTestCondition([textView isKindOfClass:[UITextView class]], error, @"The accessibility element is not a UITextView");
        NSRange range = [[textView.textStorage string] rangeOfString:text];
        KIFTestCondition(range.length > 0, error, @"The text '%@' was not found in UITextView with accessibility identifier: %@", text, identifier);
        range.length = 1;
        range = [textView.layoutManager glyphRangeForCharacterRange:range actualCharacterRange:nil];
        CGRect rect = [textView.layoutManager boundingRectForGlyphRange:range inTextContainer:textView.textContainer];
        rect = CGRectOffset(rect, textView.textContainerInset.left, textView.textContainerInset.top);
        CGPoint point = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(rect), CGRectGetMidY(rect));
        [textView longPressAtPoint:point duration:0.1f];
        return KIFTestStepResultSuccess;
    }];
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately if you have multiple text views with the same accessibility identifier (which shouldn't happen but if it does), this will fail to find the second one.